# Cannot reshape tensor with its real dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a really complicated transformer model and i need to count MRR from scratch.

*(I think the problem with dataset batches (1248 = 39*32) but I don't have enough expertise to solve it)*

So i wrote that code (separated the problem line):

```
    def _count_mrr(self, y_true: tf.Tensor, y_pred: tf.Tensor):
        y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, shape=(1, self.max_length - 1))
        y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, shape=(1, self.max_length - 1, self._data_controller._vocab_size))
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)
        y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true)
        y_pred = tf.squeeze(y_pred)

        y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, shape=(self.max_length - 1, 1))

        y_pred = tf.math.top_k(y_pred, self._data_controller._vocab_size).indices
        where_tensor = tf.equal(y_pred, y_true)
        where_tensor = tf.where(where_tensor)[:, 1]
        where_tensor = tf.cast(tf.add(where_tensor, 1), dtype=tf.dtypes.float64)
        where_tensor = tf.divide(tf.constant(np.ones(self.max_length - 1)), where_tensor)
        return tf.math.reduce_mean(where_tensor)
```

When I try to run this code it breaks with error:

```
    File "d:\Development\transformer_chatbot\chatbot\transformer.py", line 211, in _count_mrr
      y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, shape=(self.max_length - 1, 1))
Node: 'Reshape_4'
Input to reshape is a tensor with 1248 values, but the requested shape has 39
     [[{{node Reshape_4}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_39181]
```

BUT!!! if I tried to run `y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, shape=(1248, 1))` I got this:

```
    File "d:\Development\transformer_chatbot\chatbot\transformer.py", line 211, in _count_mrr  *
        y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, shape=(1248, 1))

    ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 39 elements to shape [1248,1] (1248 elements) for 
    '{{node Reshape_4}} = Reshape[T=DT_INT32, Tshape=DT_INT32](Squeeze, Reshape_4/shape)' with
    input shapes: [39], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1248,1].
```

[The full model if needed](https://github.com/zer0deck/transformer_chatbot/blob/main/chatbot/transformer.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I mentioned before the problem was in working with `tf.Dataset` batches.

Data is loaded within 3 dimensions (like `(None, maxlen-1, vocab_size)`), where `None` is hidden batch size.

At first `tf` loads 2 empty attempts with batch size 1 to check, if everything works. But the actual batch size is 32 for me.

I solved it with a more simplified `tf.reshape()` combining. I splited all my batches to a single units like:

```
start = tf.Tensor( [
            [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], 
            [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
            ], shape=(None (2),2,3))
end = tf.reshape(start, shape=(-1, 3))
>> tf.Tensor( [
            [1, 2, 3], 
            [1, 2, 3], 
            [1, 2, 3],
            [1, 2, 3],
            ], shape=(None (4),3))
```

and then work with it.

The final fix:

```
def _count_mrr(self, y_true: tf.Tensor, y_pred: tf.Tensor):
    y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, shape=(-1, 1))
    y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, shape=(-1, self._data_controller._vocab_size))
    y_pred = tf.math.top_k(y_pred, k=self._data_controller._vocab_size).indices
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)
    where_tensor = tf.equal(y_true,y_pred)
    where_tensor = tf.where(where_tensor)[:, 1]
    where_tensor = tf.cast(tf.add(where_tensor, 1), dtype=tf.dtypes.float64)
    where_tensor = tf.divide(
               tf.constant(np.ones(where_tensor._shape_as_list()[0])), 
               where_tensor)
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(where_tensor)
```

Notice, that this solution is not perfect and requires a **tremendous amount of memory** allocation for tensors.

*I hope that my experience will help other people with the same problem.*